# Invalid task 'ľf': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal

Tags: maven, installation, pom.xml, build-error

I have the error described in the picture when I am trying to execute the command below:

[image: mvn clean install]

Could you, please, help me to fix it?

In pom.xml I have:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Skip tests at build time -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- we target Java 7.0 -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- projects should be modified one at a time in eclipse
          we therefore don't use project references -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the character before f is minus sign, not a dash or hyphen?

Comment: @frant.hartm That's true. It was not minus. But now I have another error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908307/clean-install-some-modules-with-maven-results-in-an-error-error-building-pom-m